# Show hide available content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have some content in my post. But I want to hide it until I click to a link in this post. I have yet to build this site, but I will say my idea.

> 1. The first Heading
> 2. The second Heading
> 3. The third Heading
> 4. The fourth Heading
>
> /* The content following are hidden Until I clicked to a link above. */
>   /* Content is available wrapped in a div tag, do not loaded from another site. */
>
> 1. Content 1 will be show only click to "1. The first Heading"
> 2. Content 2 will be show only click to "2. The second Heading"
> 3. Content 3 will be show only click to "3. The third Heading"
> 4. Content 4 will be show only click to "4. The fourth Heading"

Can use CSS or Ajax / jQuery to create the effect?

Comment: Just use something like an accordion control: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: something like $(".firstHeading").on("click", function() { $(".content1").toggle();)};

Comment: -1 for no research effort. there are lots of tab, accordion widgets out there, as well as tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```

Here is the [complete demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show) how you can hide and show the element by click event.

Comment: Humble request: please stop sharing links to w3schools. They contain lots of outdated info. if you want to share a jquery method then link to the ocumentation or create a demo yourself...

Answer (score 2):

I have made a pure css accordion that achieves the same functionality.Checkout the following link at [codepen](http://codepen.io/dev_abhijeet/pen/mbJFh)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#first" class="acc-header">What is java Programming Language?</a>
  <div class="acc-content" id="first">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo harum vel aliquid. Quaerat soluta sed aperiam temporibus ipsum obcaecati porro commodi error unde reprehenderit ipsa, dolore id, totam dolores, quae.
    </p>
  </div></li>
    <li><a href="#second" class="acc-header">How is javascript different from java?</a>
  <div class="acc-content" id="second">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo harum vel aliquid. Quaerat soluta sed aperiam temporibus ipsum obcaecati porro commodi error unde reprehenderit ipsa, dolore id, totam dolores, quae
    </p>
  </div></li>
    <li><a href="#third" class="acc-header">Other front end technologies</a>
  <div class="acc-content" id="third">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo harum vel aliquid. Quaerat soluta sed aperiam temporibus ipsum obcaecati porro commodi error unde reprehenderit ipsa, dolore id, totam dolores, quae
    </p>
  </div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
padding-top: 50px;
font : 1em cursive;
background-image: url(http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/fantasy-winter-scenery-1920x1200.jpg);
background-size: cover;
color: #fff;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 500px;
margin: auto;
padding: 5px;
}
ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.acc-header{
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px 20px;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.7;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 2px;
margin-bottom: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.acc-content p{
margin: 10px;
}
.acc-content{
background-color: #222;
opacity: 0.7;
height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: height 0.4s ease;
-ms-transition: height 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: height 0.4s ease;
transition: height 0.4s ease;
}
.acc-content:target{
height: 170px;
}
```

Comment: yes the beauty about it is that it's made without using JS by using  powerful :target CSS selector.

Comment: I stopped actively web developing for like 10 years or so, and coming back to see all the CSS wizardry that exists is just a slap in the face sometimes.

Comment: CSS has become very powerful today. A good CSS developer is the one who achieves as many functionality as he could without using client-side scripts.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it can be pretty easy. By default you hide `.content` divs with CSS and display the corresponding one on heading click. Consider bellow example.

```js
var $content = $('.content');
$('h2').click(function() {
    $content.removeClass('show')
            .filter('.content-' + $(this).data('content'))
            .addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.content {
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #EEE;
}
.content.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 data-content="1">Heading #1</h2>
<h2 data-content="2">Heading #2</h2>
<h2 data-content="3">Heading #3</h2>

<div class="content content-1">Content #1</div>
<div class="content content-2">Content #2</div>
<div class="content content-3">Content #3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, I would recommend to load from ajax the content on first click and then hide it instead of deleting the toggled panel and retrieve it again from AJAX each time (so that there is no wait on each click and less requests).

So here's a way of doing it:

```
$('.header').click(function()
{
    var clickedHeader= $(this);
    if (clickedHeader.next().is('.toggle:visible'))
    {
        clickedHeader.next().slideDown(800);
    }
    else if (clickedHeader.next().is('.toggle:hidden'))
    {
        clickedHeader.next().slideUp(800);
    }
    else
    {
        $.get(url, data, function(data)
        {
            // First do some treatment if needed...
            clickedHeader.after('<div class="toggle" style="display:none;">'+data+'</div>');
            clickedHeader.next().slideDown(800);
        });
    }
});
```

This will work if you have HTML like this for ex.

```
<div class="header">First header</div>
<div class="header">Second header</div>
<div class="header">Third header</div>
<div class="header">Fourth header</div>
```

and after each header you would toggle a div that has class '.toggle'.

Hope it helps.